# My Nav icon does not close

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi there I am trying to create a side nav, and I cannot manage to close the menu with a second function of "onclick()"

the navigation opens perfectly but then it does not close.
Here is my fiddle, I was just hoping to get help on having a added onlick function that closes the nav when clicking on the nav icon again.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "220px";
  document.getElementById("Content").style.paddingLeft = "0px";
  document.body.style.opacity = "0.1";

}
```

```css
/* The side navigation menu */

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 400;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 90px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/* The navigation menu links */

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #00CB10;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.menu-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 96%;
}
.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 5px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 5px);
}
/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
}
```

```html
<div id="Menu" class="menu-icon" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <!--Start Side Nav-->
  <a href="#">Our Story</a>
  <a href="#">Products</a>
  <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a href="#">Login/Sign up</a>
</div>
<!---->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set the width in JS. You are toggling an additionnal class when the menu is open, you can play with this.

Another point is that you shouldn't change the body opacity (it will affect the menu too), but only the main content div.
Or display an overlay div with a fixed position (100% width and height, background and opacity) so it creates an effect of disabled content.

In my exemple I commented the unnecessary js lines, and I added somme CSS :

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  //document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "220px";
  //document.getElementById("Content").style.paddingLeft = "0px";
  document.body.style.opacity = "0.1";

}
```

```css
/* The side navigation menu */

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 400;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 90px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/* The navigation menu links */

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #00CB10;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.menu-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 96%;
}
.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 5px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 5px);
}
/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
}
.change + .sidenav {
  width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Menu" class="menu-icon" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <!--Start Side Nav-->
  <a href="#">Our Story</a>
  <a href="#">Products</a>
  <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a href="#">Login/Sign up</a>
</div>
<!---->
```

Comment: I did not know it was toggling a additional class. I actually thought I needed a extra onclick function to close the nav but this worked perfectly thank you. So basically the .change + .sidenav toggles the width to switch?

Comment: `x.classList.toggle("change");` is toggling the class change on the element `x` (here #Menu). The class  `change` is the one used to make the menu button shape change. So I used that class to change the menu width too.

Comment: `.change + .sidenav` in CSS means it will search for an element with class `sidenav` just after the element with the class `change`. As `change`will only appear when you open the menu, the CSS effect will only apply when it's supposed to be opened

Answer (score 1):

I have added new `class` called `toggleClass` and I have provided `width:220px`, and I have commented `document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "220px"`

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7dzedes/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the width in javascript,then you can go for a check whether the menu is open or not.

However the above answer is more appropriate in this case.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  var width=document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width;
  if(width!="220px" || width=="") 
  {
     document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width="220px";
  }
  else
  {
     document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width="0px";
  }
  document.getElementById("Content").style.paddingLeft = "0px";
  document.body.style.opacity = "0.1";

}
```

```css
/* The side navigation menu */

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 400;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 90px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/* The navigation menu links */

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #00CB10;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.menu-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 96%;
}
.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 5px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 5px);
}
/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
}
```

```html
<div id="Menu" class="menu-icon" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <!--Start Side Nav-->
  <a href="#">Our Story</a>
  <a href="#">Products</a>
  <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a href="#">Login/Sign up</a>
</div>
<!---->
```

Answer (score 0):

The key thing missing from your set up is that `#mySidenav` needs to be able to toggle between states *as well as* `.menu-icon`.

Consequently, you need to set up `myFunction()` so that it toggles the class `.change` on *both* `.menu-icon` *and* `#mySidenav`.

```js
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-icon')[0]; 
var mySidenav = document.getElementById('mySidenav');

x.classList.toggle('change');
mySidenav.classList.toggle('change');
}

var menuIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-icon')[0];
menuIcon.addEventListener('click',myFunction,false);
```

```css
/* The side navigation menu */

.sidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
/* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
position: fixed;
z-index: 400;
right: 0;
background-color: #0F0F0F;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 90px;
transition: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
opacity: 0.8;
}
/* The navigation menu links */

.sidenav a {
padding: 8px 8px 8px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: right;
vertical-align: middle;
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
line-height: 20px;
color: #FFFFFF;
transition: 0.3s;
}
/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
color: #00CB10;
text-decoration: underline;
}
.menu-icon {
display: inline-block;
position: fixed;
z-index: 500;
cursor: pointer;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: 96%;
}
.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
width: 30px;
height: 4px;
background-color: #0F0F0F;
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 6px 0;
transition: 0.4s;
}
/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 5px);
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 5px);
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
opacity: 0;
}
/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

#mySidenav.change {
width: 220px;
}

#Content.change {
padding-left: 0;
}

body.change {
opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<div id="Menu" class="menu-icon">
<div class="bar1"></div>
<div class="bar2"></div>
<div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<!--Start Side Nav-->
<a href="#">Our Story</a>
<a href="#">Products</a>
<a href="#">Contact Us</a>
<a href="#">Login/Sign up</a>
</div>
```